# Conda returns Solving Environment: Done -- hangs with all processes

Tags: anaconda, conda

I recently ran conda update --all. Conda successfully updated many packages and I can still run scripts I have written successfully.

However, now when I try and update or remove any packages, or try and create a new virtual environment conda returns "Solving Environment: Done" and then does not make any progress.

Any ideas on how to trouble-shoot?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @GabrielFair I literally uninstalled and reinstalled the Anaconda distribution to fix it.

Comment: yeah, thats what I ended up doing as well. :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

It seemed like pressing Enter somehow forced the command line to display some progress and continue.